# How to convert latin1 table to utf8 with serialized values?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character, iso-8859-1

I have to convert some huge tables (>60 GB) from latin1 to utf8 and I'm looking for the best practice. One problem is that some tables contain serialized php objects.

My first approach was to set the TEXT columns to BLOB, convert the character set to utf8 and convert the columns back to TEXT, but I got some issues with the last step (incorrect string value: '\xE4\xF6\xFC\xDF";...').

What would be the best strategy to convert the values properly to utf8?

Comment: Beware that [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize) output is not supposed to be plain text: *Note that this is a binary string which may include null bytes, and needs to be stored and handled as such. For example, serialize() output should generally be stored in a BLOB field in a database, rather than a CHAR or TEXT field*

Answer (score 0):

*Given* that the data is in latin1 encoding, such as the `äöüß` in your example, *and* that the column is `CHARACTER SET latin1`, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases , which says

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

(or utf8)

Note:  That will change the charset for all text columns in the one table; and only the one table.